# PowerShell Filter from Array based on Email separated by semi-colon, Object value in the array separated by pipe

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have two arrays in a PowerShell script

Array1 - Each object is separated by semi-colon. Object value in the array has Email and Name separated by pipe. The array is retrieved from search API using PnP PowerShell from a SharePoint list.

```
$searchAPIData = @("Bill@myDomain.com|Bill";"Paul@myDomain.com|Paul";"Mike@myDomain.com|mike";"Mark@myDomain.com|Mark";"Sam@myDomain.com|Sam")
```

Array 2 - Fetches data from a standalone list. Each object is separated by semi-colon. But the Object value in the array has Email and User ID.

```
$existingDataInList = @("Bill@myDomain.com|3";"Paul@myDomain.com|2";"John@myDomain.com|5";"Mark@myDomain.com|4")
```

Back Ground - For each email, I am using yammer API to fetch User ID. So instead of making multiple API calls, If I filter for specific items, the API calls can be reduced. I compare based on emails. If the emails are same in both the arrays, then I don't need to call API/ or perform any operations.

If emails are different in both the arrays, then I need to update the data back to the SharePoint list only for items that are present in Array1 and not in Array 2. And a reverse case where items present in array2 and not in array 1 should be removed.

In the above example,
-- I need to filter/extract `"Mike@myDomain.com|mike"` and `"Sam@myDomain.com|Sam"` from Array1. So only 2 API calls are made.

-- I need to remove `"John@myDomain.com|5"` from Array2.

I tried using Where , `-NotContains $_` or `-Contains $_` and is not giving me desired results. Same for Where-Object.

Any inputs are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the elements to be matched are of different format, consider building hash tables and using the mathcing part as the hash key. Like so,

```
$searchAPIData = @("Bill@myDomain.com|Bill";"Paul@myDomain.com|Paul";"Mike@myDomain.com|mike";"Mark@myDomain.com|Mark";"Sam@myDomain.com|Sam")
$ht1 = @{}
# Split content into two elements, use 1st as key, 2nd as value
$searchAPIData | % { $s = $_.split('|'); $ht1.add($s[0], $s[1]) }

$existingDataInList = @("Bill@myDomain.com|3";"Paul@myDomain.com|2";"John@myDomain.com|5";"Mark@myDomain.com|4")
$ht2 = @{}
$existingDataInList | % { $s = $_.split('|'); $ht2.add($s[0], $s[1]) }
```

So, what good does this do? Let's see the hashtable contents.

```
PS /> $ht1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Bill@myDomain.com              Bill
Paul@myDomain.com              Paul
Mike@myDomain.com              mike
Mark@myDomain.com              Mark
Sam@myDomain.com               Sam

PS /> $ht2

Name                           Value
----                           -----
John@myDomain.com              5
Bill@myDomain.com              3
Paul@myDomain.com              2
Mark@myDomain.com              4

PS />
```

Note that now the emails (or UPNs quite likely) are in same format. The rest of the data is set in each hashtable key's value for further usage.

Now, let's compare the hashtables. Get an enumerator for hashtable and use it to look for entity on the other hashtable based on hash key. Like so,

```
foreach($e in $ht1.GetEnumerator()) { 
  if(-not $ht2.containskey($e.name)) {
    write-output $("Didn't find {0} {1} from list" -f $e.name, $e.value)
  } 
}
Didn't find Mike@myDomain.com mike from list
Didn't find Sam@myDomain.com Sam from list

foreach($e in $ht2.GetEnumerator()) { 
  if(-not $ht1.containskey($e.name)) {
    write-output $("Didn't find {0} {1} from list" -f $e.name, $e.value)
  } 
}
Didn't find John@myDomain.com 5 from list
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This worked. Have another question though.
Instead of arrays, if both are strings like 

string1 = "Bill@myDomain.com|Bill;Paul@myDomain.com|Paul;Mike@myDomain.com|mike;Mark@myDomain.com|Mark;Sam@myDomain.com|Sam"

string2 = "Bill@myDomain.com|3;Paul@myDomain.com|2;John@myDomain.com|5;Mark@myDomain.com|4"

How to compare here?

Comment: Then you convert the strings into arrays by doing a `-split ';'`. That'll give you an array that's the same than in the original question.

Comment: Thought so. Thank you again for the updates :)